# Angularjs directive 1 excecute function in directive 2

Tags: angularjs

I've two directives. And when I change some data in directive One I need to excecute a function in directive two.

My current idea is, to have a shared service where I set a property I can watch in directive two and change the value in directive one and the watcher in directive two excecutes my function.

Are there some better solutions for such kind of problem and interdirective communication?

Comment: have a look at [publish subscribe pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Publish%E2%80%93subscribe_pattern)

Comment: need more information? are those two directive nested in each other(if yes then just go for `require` attribute of directive) **OR** they are placed in different location(go for pub/sub pattern)..

Comment: different location not nested no parent directives  - at the moment when we need one to get a better solution fpr this problem then I will add one.

Comment: @smnbbrv when I google for the pattern and angularjs all implementations use broadcast and I thought broadcast should be used when you have multiple directives where I need to execute a function

Comment: @squadwuschel standard angular broadcasting is heavy and going through all scopes, when your goal is to deliver event from one directive only to those recepients who does subscribe. If you are looking for implementation have a look at [js-signals](https://millermedeiros.github.io/js-signals/). I used it for a while for that purpose